# EmberJS: Resolve promise in the success of processing request

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, vert.x

I adapted the ajax call in RESTAdapter for retrieving the data from vert.x bus bridge. But, I have a problem with retrieving the promise in the success part of processing request.

I suppose that the problem is with form of data structure that Ember expects. 
This is the code of my adapter:

```
var VertxAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  protocol: 'http',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: '4200',
  addressMapping: {
    "GET localhost/mindMaps": "mindMaps.list"
  },
  pendingRequests: [],

  vertx: function() {
    var adapter = this;

    if (typeof adapter._vertx === 'undefined') {
      adapter._vertx = new vertx.EventBus(adapter.protocol + '://' + adapter.host + ':' + adapter.port + '/eventbus');
      console.log('initialize vertx');
      adapter._vertx.onopen = function() { 
        // TODO: register for messages send from server to this client

        adapter.processPendingRequests.apply(adapter);
      };
    }

    return adapter._vertx;
  },

  ajax: function(url, type, params) {
   console.log(url, type, params);

    var adapter = this;

    var messageAddress = adapter.addressMapping[type + " " + url];

    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var success = function(json) {
        Ember.run(null, resolve, json);
      };
      var error = function(json) {
        Ember.run(null, reject, json);
      };

      if(adapter.vertx().readyState === vertx.EventBus.OPEN) {
        console.log('ready state');
        adapter.processRequest(messageAddress, params, success, error);

      } else {
        var pendingReq = {
          address: messageAddress,
          params: params,
          success: success,
          error: error
        };
        console.log('push pending req');
        adapter.pendingRequests.push(pendingReq);

      }

    });

  },

  processPendingRequests: function() {
    console.log('processPendingRequests');
    var adapter = this;
      adapter.pendingRequests.forEach(function(req){
        console.log(req);
          adapter.processRequest(req.address, req.params, req.success, req.error);
      });
  },

  processRequest: function(address, params, success, error) {
    console.log(address, params, success, error);
    var adapter = this;
    adapter.vertx().send(address, params, function(json){
      //TODO: implement
      //console.log(arguments);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(json));

     success(json);

      // error(json);

    });

    adapter.pendingRequests = [];
  }

});

export default VertxAdapter.extend({
    port: '8080'
});
```

And this is the server:

```
var eventBus = require("vertx/event_bus");
var mindMaps = {};

var extend = function(obj, props) {
   for (var prop in props) {
      if (props.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
         obj[prop] = props[prop];
      }
   }

   return obj;
};

eventBus.registerHandler("mindMaps.list", function(args, responder) {
    responder(
    {
        "data": Object.keys(mindMaps).map(function(key) {
            return extend(
                {
                    "type": "mindMaps"
                },
                mindMaps[key]
            );
        })
    });
});

eventBus.registerHandler("mindMaps.save", function(mindMap, responder) {
    if (!mindMap.id) {
        mindMap.id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    }
    mindMaps[mindMap.id] = mindMap;
    responder({
        "data": mindMap
    });
});

eventBus.registerHandler("mindMaps.delete", function(args, responder) {
    delete mindMaps[args.id];
    responder({});
});
```

Here is the console output:

```
{"data":[{"type":"mindMaps","name":"One","id":59},{"type":"mindMaps","name":"Two","id":99},{"type":"mindMaps","name":"Three","id":55}]}

WARNING: Encountered "data" in payload, but no model was found for model name "datum" (resolved model name using mind-maps@serializer:-rest:.typeForRoot("data"))

Error while processing route: mind-maps Assertion Failed: The response from a findAll must be an Array, not undefined Error: Assertion Failed: The response from a findAll must be an Array, not undefined
```

I suppose that I don't return the data from the server in a form that Ember expects me to.

Ideas?

BR,
Milan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you also want to create your own serializer, your JSON needs to be in a specific format. You can see the format documented [here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#toc_json-structure).

If you're not able to modify your server to return that JSON format, you'll need to write your own [Serializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Serializer.html), and convert your data into the format listed [here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_push).

If this sounds a little bit much, that's because it is. I think Ember-Data's adapters and serializers is its number one issue. Unfortunately, there aren't many easy ways to do what you want.

Comment: Yep, I changed the format of the JSON on the server side and now everything works. Thanks.